# How to svn merge two branches in command line

Tags: svn, merge

I checkout other people's branch. Inside, I do

```
   svn merge http://repo.com/apps/service/branches/my_branch http://repo.com/apps/service/branches/your_branch
```

What is the correct way to do svn merge in cli? The command above gives

```
Merging differences between repository URLs into '.':
 G   .
Recording mergeinfo for merge between repository URLs into '.':
 U   .
```

when I do svn commit -m "xxx". It seems nothing happened.
What is the correct to merge 1 branch?

Answer (score 1):

I expect you want to merge changes from `your_branch` into `my_branch`? please **update your question** accordingly, it is not clear what you want to merge from where.

You need to have a checked out working copy to merge into. Also I expect it is your current directory as otherwise the merge command fails. However, it is not clear to which SVN branch this Workingcopy points so please **state this** as well. I expect this is `my_branch` in your case.

You performed a *"2-URL merge"* which is: showing you the difference between `my_branch` and `your_branch` and merge them into working copy (`my_branch`). In the result it will be the same as `your_branch` undoing all changes done on `my_branch` (`my_branch`+ [`your_branch`-`my_branch`] = `your_branch`).

What you usually want is a *"complete merge"*. Just state the branch you want to merge from and the changes will be applied to your working copy:

`svn merge http://repo.com/apps/service/branches/your_branch`

This will show up  all changes from `your_branch` in `my_branch`

To complete the list: the 3rd merge is *"cherry-pick merge"* and looks like "complete merge" but selects certain revisions to merge.

Comment: On server, I make a branch. My friend makes a branch. I checkout his branch into my machine. I merge it with my branch and check into friend's branch. Basically, I merge on someone's behalf.

Comment: I think I was doing your_branch+ [your_branch-my_branch], which is not correct.

Comment: if you checked out "your_branch", go to the workingcopy and call "svn merge http://repo.com/apps/service/branches/my_branch" this should merge your changes into "your_branch"